# how to get updated data from fs.watch in nodejs when ever there is update in file

Tags: node.js, csv, watch, fs

I am trying to get updated data from a file when ever there is a change in the file i am using fs.watch for watching changes but how to get updated data so that i can parse csv to json

nodejs code:

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
 var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var converter = new Converter({constructResult:false});

fs.createReadStream("test.xlsx").pipe(converter);
//record_parsed will be emitted each csv row being processed 
converter.on("record_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
   console.log(jsonObj); //here is your result json obje

app.get("/",function(req,res)
{
 console.log("listening\n");
 fs.watch('test.csv', function (event, filename) {
  console.log('event is: ' + event);

//record_parsed will be emitted each csv row being processed 
converter.on("record_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
   console.log(jsonObj); //here is your result json object 
});
});

});

 app.listen(8180);
 console.log("running");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [tail-stream](https://github.com/Juul/tail-stream) or at least peek at its source code.

It extends [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) and uses `fs.watch` to execute `stream.read(0)` when `change` event occurs. Still, there is a lot of work to properly handle EOF, deletion of file etc., if you decide to implement it yourself.

Comment: can you provide any sample code or any reference where i can achieve this

and how to handle EOF!

Comment: So this tail-stream will give the updated data like if a file is there if i added a new row to the file then this new data will be given by tail-stream am i right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933201/tail-stream-module-in-nodejs-is-not-printing-last-record-of-the-file

Comment: taill-stream is not printing the last record is this the behaviour of it?