# tail-stream module in nodejs is not printing last record of the file

Tags: node.js, csv, stream, fs

I am using tail-stream to get data from a csv file and converting each csv record to json format and printing it.

But tail-stream is not printing the last line of the file it is keeping it as a buffer, and if I update the file all the rows from previous last(the buffered last row) row to updated last row(excluding last row) are printed, its again storing the latest last row in buffer

So is this the behavior of the tail-stream or is there any wrong in my code

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tail-stream

My code:

```
var tailStream      = require('tail-stream');
var Converter       = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var converter  = new Converter({constructResult:false});

var logStream = tailStream.createReadStream('issue_Approver_Rohit1.csv', {
    beginAt: 0,
    onMove: 'follow',
    detectTruncate: false,
    onTruncate: 'end',
    endOnError: false
});


logStream.pipe(converter);


converter.on("record_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
        console.log(jsonObj); //here is your result json object

    });

});
```

Comment: This might be caused by your csv. Are you adding a newLine at the end of the last item?

Comment: well my csv file is like an excel file with .csv extension

Comment: i extracted my csv file from excel spread sheet